# how to speed up image loading in caffe?

Tags: gpu, caffe, conv-neural-network

While training a CNN using caffe, between every iteration printed out, I get between 3 and 5 repetitions of the following warning:

```
blocking_queue.cpp:50] Waiting for data
```

I'm using the default caffe settings in that I made an lmdb database using the provided script. The images are 200x200px tifs, about 30-50kB before loading into the lmdb.

How should I diagnose where the slowdown is? I.e. what part of the hardware chain would need to be upgraded, or what I can do with software to speed the processing up. I'm using GeForce GTX 980 GPUs with CUDA Version 7.5.18.

Comment: is it possible that the lmdb data set is sotred on a network drive? could you possibly be suffering from slow network connection?

Comment: The lmdb file is stored on a direct access local drive, a Samsung SSD SM87

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a problem with your I/O chain.  Do you have an application to monitor I/O capability to the device?  Is there slow response at at the same time as "Waiting for data"?

One possible workaround is to increase the batch size: reading in more data at once will keep your model busy longer and give the I/O routines more time to fetch the next data block.

Comment: how would one monitor their I/O capability? Is there a way to control the pre-fetching of data in Caffe?

Comment: You're asking for off-site tools and tutorial help -- too broad, and specifically off-topic for Stack Overflow.